# ROS of sick_tim series lidar's drivers package

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am a beginner of ROS system. Now I need to use it to receive and show the sick_tim561 lidar's datas, I already have installed the Ubuntu OS and Jade ROS. But I really don't have any idea about how to install of package as following link: http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim
I will be grateful if someone can kindly give me some direction.
Thanks for your kindly help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221947/ros-of-sick_tim-series-lidar%27s-drivers-package/) by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2015-12-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-sick-tim` ?

---

Originally posted by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) with karma: 3561 on 2015-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-04**:
Thanks for your reply sincerely.
But I still have some question about this topic.
Follow this link: http://wiki.ros.org/sick_tim
There are 6 parts in it, my question are:
The first(Choosing the right branch) and second(Supported scanner types) parts are not problem for me

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-04**:
Because I already installed the Jade ROS and my lidar is in the supported scanner types.
But in the the "Pack Summary", there is a "Source" with the link"git https://github.com/uos/sick_tim.git (branch: jade)", should I download it and put it somewhere in my computer?

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-04**:
Choosing the branch is for source installation. Since you will install using debian package, skip this topic. We select the ROS distro with "`-jade-`" part in the package name I wrote. For the second topic, since you have TiM561, you will run `sick_tim551_2050001` node.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-04**:
And in the third part(ROS API), there are 2 parts in it which are "Published Topics"  and "Parameters".
I click the links and see so much codes in it. Should I execute the codes in the Ubuntu's terminal?

Sorry for asking so much question, it would be very grateful for your reply.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-04**:
Did you go over [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)? Topics are used for gathering scan data etc. Parameters are for configuration of your LIDAR and node. You will not execute codes for this. You will run the node with necessary parameters and get your scan data from `/scan` topic.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-07**:
I read the tutorial these days. I use the command "git clone" to install the source from the package summary and I can see the some program is running, but it shows that USB can't be connected. (I use USB to connect to my com) I also change the port in the parameter, but I'm not sure is it right way

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-07**:
You can supply these (command you run, error messages you get etc.) in detail by editing your question.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-07**:
Dot. Akif, could I have your contact way because it will be clear if we use pictures to show the problem. Thank you very much for your kindly help.

**Comment by [Akif](https://answers.ros.org/users/23527/akif/) on 2015-12-07**:
@Terry Su, if will be better for the community if you can solve your problem here. It will help other users having same problems.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-08**:
I reinstalled the Jade and sick_tim package summary source again. When I finished the installation, I go to the folder where is the sick package to find the tim_551 file(Path: sick_tim -> launch -> sick_tim_551_2050000.launch) to modify the IP and port number (by the gedit).

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-08**:
In the launch, I modified the parameter which is for the IP and port  for my lidar shows as below:
param name="hostname" type="string" value="192.168.1.144"  and  param name="port" type="string" value="2111"

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-08**:
And as below is the error:
SOPAS - Error stopping streaming scan data!
sick_tim driver exiting.
[ERROR] [1449564970.050295992]: No SICK TiM devices connected!
[FATAL] [1449564970.050344550]: Failed to init device: 1
^C[sick_tim551_2050001-3] killing on exit
[robot_state_publisher-2] killing on exit

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-08**:
I put the link here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6iIqQqNZmCQNmFfVnJ3Z3prckk

**Comment by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) on 2015-12-08**:
did you uncomment the  following line? https://github.com/uos/sick_tim/blob/indigo/launch/sick_tim551_2050001.launch#L22. Also you need to make your document public so we can see it.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-08**:
This is my sick_tim_561_2010101.launch code: https://github.com/TerryGP/sick_tim/blob/patch-1/launch/sick_tim_561_2050101.launch , I have already uncomment the part of TCP instead before, but it doen't work.

**Comment by [Terry Su](https://answers.ros.org/users/25230/terry-su/) on 2015-12-09**:
These are the all the file of my sick folder in this link: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B6iIqQqNZmCQZmVBeU92aWFVdVU . I am a beginner of Github, therefore I can't make a same folder as you send to me in a short time. I use google cloud disk instead of it. But I will make a one in the future.